# Progressing bootstrap progress-bar even on windows resize

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap progress-bar that should progress from 0% to 100% using 10% increments. The bar should automatically adjust when the window is resized. For example while the bar is progressing and its 50% and if I resize the window, it should still be 50% width.

However my code behaves erratically. Sometimes it stops and I have to resize the window to get the bar to progress to 100%.

The progress-bar with id = bar is defined in the body. The complete  is as follows:

```
<!-- JUMBOTRON with Logo and Links -->
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background:url(grass.png);background-size:1000px;background-repeat:repeat-x;padding-top:10px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <img src="logo.gif" width="50px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">LINK 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">LINK 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">LINK 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">LINK 4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p style="color:white;">THIS IS A JUMBOTRON</p>
    </div>
<!-- Main container -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Progress Bar -->
    <p>PROGRESS</p>
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div id="bar" class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am changing the width attribute using jquery. The complete  section is as follows:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>CLEAN</title>
        <meta name="description" content="clean-page">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var bar = $("#bar");
  var bar_width;
  var width;
  var percentage;
  var newVal;

  var progress = setInterval(function () 
  {
    bar_width = $("#bar").width();
    width = ($(window).width());
    percentage = (Math.round(((bar_width/width)*100)/10)*10);

    if (percentage >= 100) 
    {
      clearInterval(progress);
      $('.progress').removeClass('active');
      $("#bar").width("100%");
     } 
     else 
     {
       percentage = percentage + 10;
       newVal = percentage + '%';
       $("#bar").width(newVal);
      }

  $("#bar").text(percentage + "%");
  }, 100);
</script>
```

I am just starting off with HTML, BOOTSTRAP, JQUERY. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the bar should automatically adjust when the window is resized?"

Comment: Can you show us the 3 divs in your html before the one you displayed, it seems to be an issue up there.

Comment: @APAD1: When window is resized, the proportion should remain

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Please see complete website code updated above.

Comment: @flukeperf can you post the css associated with this code please `<div class="container">

    <!-- Progress Bar -->
    <p>PROGRESS</p>
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div id="bar" class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>

</div>`

Comment: I have a hunch that either the container or the progress progress-striped active, sizes are using the wrong relative sizes. Your javascript looks good and should not be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
```

when you add `aria-valuenow="60"`,`aria-valuemin="0"`,`aria-valuemax="100"` I think It should work correctly.

also dont forget to add `role="progressbar"`